# android studio and flask server

Tags: python, java, android, flask

```
`import io

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload_file', methods=['POST'])
#@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def receive_file_contents():
    file_contents = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    #file_content = request.data.decode('utf-8')
    #result = {'message': 'File processed successfully'}
    return file_contents, 200

    # Process the file contents as needed
    # You can perform computations, manipulations, or store the data in a database

    #return "File contents received and processed successfully"
    #return file_contents
@app.route('/download_file', methods=['GET'])
def download_file():
    # Generate the file content here
    file_content = b'This is the file content'

    # Return the file content as a file download
    return send_file(io.BytesIO(file_content), as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=12345)`
```

```
`public class socket_test extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    private static final String SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int SERVER_PORT =12345;
    private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:12345/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file);

        //textView = findViewById(R.id.FileName);
    }

    public void selectFile(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }

                inputStream.close();

                String fileContent = stringBuilder.toString();

                // Send the file content to the Python server
                sendToServer(fileContent);

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, output.class);
                intent.putExtra("fileContent", fileContent);
                startActivity(intent);

                // Update the text of the TextView with the file content
                //textView.setText(fileContent);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /*private void sendToServer(String message) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
                    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                    outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }*/
    private void sendToServer(String fileContent) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                            .addFormDataPart("fileContent", fileContent)
                            .build();

                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(SERVER_URL)
                            .post(requestBody)
                            .build();

                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}`
```

first one is python code for flask server.  second one is java code in android studio.  What I want to do is, when I select a file in Android, the text file is passed to the flask server. So, we will apply the Python code to that file and send the result back to the Android application. is this possible without db? tell me the way how to do this...

Comment: this is possible, in this scenario no need to pass the whole file to the server. just send the content. and send back the Python code you generate. and write a logic in the android java side to write it into a file with .py as the extension.  I hope this is clear! cheers!

Comment: if you possible, can you give me the code?